# JSON into MYSQL TABLE with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

Trying to Insert the JSON File into MYSQL TABLE using PHP, Trying to loop through the JSON File but it just inserts the first row, I am a beginner so please help, below is my PHP code

```
$host = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "Portfolio";
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname) or die('Error in Connecting: ' . mysqli_error($con));


$st = mysqli_prepare($con, 'INSERT INTO completetsxtickers (summaryDetailmaxAge,summaryDetailpriceHint,summaryDetailpreviousClose,summaryDetailopen,
                    summaryDetaildayLow,summaryDetaildayHigh,summaryDetailregularMarketPreviousClose,summaryDetailregularMarketOpen,summaryDetailregularMarketDayLow,
                    summaryDetailregularMarketDayHigh,summaryDetaildividendRate,summaryDetaildividendYield,summaryDetailexDividendDate,summaryDetailpayoutRatio,
                    summaryDetailfiveYearAvgDividendYield,summaryDetailbeta,summaryDetailtrailingPE,summaryDetailforwardPE,summaryDetailvolume,
                    summaryDetailregularMarketVolume,summaryDetailaverageVolume,summaryDetailaverageVolume10days,summaryDetailaverageDailyVolume10Day,summaryDetailbid,
                    summaryDetailask,summaryDetailbidSize,summaryDetailaskSize,summaryDetailmarketCap,summaryDetailfiftyTwoWeekLow,summaryDetailfiftyTwoWeekHigh,
                    summaryDetailpriceToSalesTrailing12Months,summaryDetailfiftyDayAverage,summaryDetailtwoHundredDayAverage,summaryDetailtrailingAnnualDividendRate,
                    summaryDetailtrailingAnnualDividendYield,summaryDetailcurrency,summaryDetailfromCurrency,summaryDetaillastMarket,summaryDetailalgorithm,
                    summaryDetailtradeable,pricemaxAge,priceregularMarketChangePercent,priceregularMarketChange,priceregularMarketTime,pricepriceHint,
                    priceregularMarketPrice,priceregularMarketDayHigh,priceregularMarketDayLow,priceregularMarketVolume,priceaverageDailyVolume10Day,
                    priceaverageDailyVolume3Month,priceregularMarketPreviousClose,priceregularMarketSource,priceregularMarketOpen,priceexchange,priceexchangeName,
                    priceexchangeDataDelayedBy,pricemarketState,pricequoteType,pricesymbol,priceunderlyingSymbol,priceshortName,pricelongName,pricecurrency,
                    pricequoteSourceName,pricecurrencySymbol,pricefromCurrency,pricelastMarket,pricemarketCap)
                               VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 
                                       ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 
                                       ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');

// bind variables to insert query params

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($st, 'sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss', $summaryDetailmaxAge,$summaryDetailpriceHint,
    $summaryDetailpreviousClose,$summaryDetailopen,
    $summaryDetaildayLow,$summaryDetaildayHigh,$summaryDetailregularMarketPreviousClose,$summaryDetailregularMarketOpen,$summaryDetailregularMarketDayLow,
    $summaryDetailregularMarketDayHigh,$summaryDetaildividendRate,$summaryDetaildividendYield,$summaryDetailexDividendDate,$summaryDetailpayoutRatio,
    $summaryDetailfiveYearAvgDividendYield,$summaryDetailbeta,$summaryDetailtrailingPE,$summaryDetailforwardPE,$summaryDetailvolume,
    $summaryDetailregularMarketVolume,$summaryDetailaverageVolume,$summaryDetailaverageVolume10days,$summaryDetailaverageDailyVolume10Day,$summaryDetailbid,
    $summaryDetailask,$summaryDetailbidSize,$summaryDetailaskSize,$summaryDetailmarketCap,$summaryDetailfiftyTwoWeekLow,$summaryDetailfiftyTwoWeekHigh,
    $summaryDetailpriceToSalesTrailing12Months,$summaryDetailfiftyDayAverage,$summaryDetailtwoHundredDayAverage,$summaryDetailtrailingAnnualDividendRate,
    $summaryDetailtrailingAnnualDividendYield,$summaryDetailcurrency,$summaryDetailfromCurrency,$summaryDetaillastMarket,$summaryDetailalgorithm,
    $summaryDetailtradeable,$pricemaxAge,$priceregularMarketChangePercent,$priceregularMarketChange,$priceregularMarketTime,$pricepriceHint,
    $priceregularMarketPrice,$priceregularMarketDayHigh,$priceregularMarketDayLow,$priceregularMarketVolume,$priceaverageDailyVolume10Day,
    $priceaverageDailyVolume3Month,$priceregularMarketPreviousClose,$priceregularMarketSource,$priceregularMarketOpen,$priceexchange,$priceexchangeName,
    $priceexchangeDataDelayedBy,$pricemarketState,$pricequoteType,$pricesymbol,$priceunderlyingSymbol,$priceshortName,$pricelongName,$pricecurrency,
    $pricequoteSourceName,$pricecurrencySymbol,$pricefromCurrency,$pricelastMarket,$pricemarketCap);

$filename = 'testing.json';

$json = file_get_contents($filename);

$data = json_decode($json, true);

var_dump($data);

foreach ($data as $row)
{

    $summaryDetailmaxAge = $row['summaryDetail']['maxAge'];
    $summaryDetailpriceHint = $row['summaryDetail']['priceHint'];
    $summaryDetailpreviousClose = $row['summaryDetail']['previousClose'];
    $summaryDetailopen = $row['summaryDetail']['open'];
    $summaryDetaildayLow = $row['summaryDetail']['dayLow'];
    ....
    ....
    

    mysqli_stmt_execute($st);

}
```

MY JSON File below, cant seem to loop through it, its a list of Tickers and values which I am trying to insert into a MYSQL Table

```
       {
    "AC.TO": {
        "summaryDetail": {
          "maxAge": 1,
          "priceHint": 2,
          "previousClose": 25.5,
          "open": 25.83,
          "dayLow": 25.2,
          "dayHigh": 25.9,
          "regularMarketPreviousClose": 25.5,
          "regularMarketOpen": 25.83,
          "regularMarketDayLow": 25.2,
          "regularMarketDayHigh": 25.9,
          "payoutRatio": 0,
          "beta": 2.481872,
          "forwardPE": -103.56,
          "volume": 2536872,
          "regularMarketVolume": 2536872,
          "averageVolume": 3607496,
          "averageVolume10days": 2868300,
          "averageDailyVolume10Day": 2868300,
          "bid": 25.51,
          "ask": 25.52,
          "bidSize": 0,
          "askSize": 0,
          "marketCap": 8666910720,
          "fiftyTwoWeekLow": 14.48,
          "fiftyTwoWeekHigh": 31,
          "priceToSalesTrailing12Months": 3.0517292,
          "fiftyDayAverage": 26.889706,
          "twoHundredDayAverage": 25.156204,
          "currency": "CAD",
          "fromCurrency": null,
          "lastMarket": null,
          "algorithm": null,
          "tradeable": false
        },
        "price": {
          "maxAge": 1,
          "regularMarketChangePercent": 0.015294094,
          "regularMarketChange": 0.3899994,
          "regularMarketTime": "2021-07-02 13:00:00",
          "priceHint": 2,
          "regularMarketPrice": 25.89,
          "regularMarketDayHigh": 25.9,
          "regularMarketDayLow": 25.2,
          "regularMarketVolume": 2536872,
          "averageDailyVolume10Day": 2868300,
          "averageDailyVolume3Month": 3607496,
          "regularMarketPreviousClose": 25.5,
          "regularMarketSource": "FREE_REALTIME",
          "regularMarketOpen": 25.83,
          "exchange": "TOR",
          "exchangeName": "Toronto",
          "exchangeDataDelayedBy": 15,
          "marketState": "CLOSED",
          "quoteType": "EQUITY",
          "symbol": "AC.TO",
          "underlyingSymbol": null,
          "shortName": "AIR CANADA",
          "longName": "Air Canada",
          "currency": "CAD",
          "quoteSourceName": "Delayed Quote",
          "currencySymbol": "$",
          "fromCurrency": null,
          "lastMarket": null,
          "marketCap": 8666910720
        }
      },
    "SCR.TO": {
        "summaryDetail": {
          "maxAge": 1,
          "priceHint": 2,
          "previousClose": 24.86,
          "open": 25.24,
          "dayLow": 23.59,
          "dayHigh": 24.94,
          "regularMarketPreviousClose": 24.86,
          "regularMarketOpen": 25.24,
          "regularMarketDayLow": 23.59,
          "regularMarketDayHigh": 24.94,
          "payoutRatio": 0,
          "beta": 2.638101,
          "forwardPE": -40.28814,
          "volume": 187927,
          "regularMarketVolume": 187927,
          "averageVolume": 389974,
          "averageVolume10days": 686057,
          "averageDailyVolume10Day": 686057,
          "bid": 24.72,
          "ask": 24.76,
          "marketCap": 1196655488,
          "fiftyTwoWeekLow": 5.5,
          "fiftyTwoWeekHigh": 56.7,
          "priceToSalesTrailing12Months": 63.048233,
          "fiftyDayAverage": 22.763824,
          "twoHundredDayAverage": 27.056059,
          "currency": "CAD",
          "fromCurrency": null,
          "lastMarket": null,
          "algorithm": null,
          "tradeable": false
        },
        "price": {
          "maxAge": 1,
          "regularMarketChangePercent": -0.043845546,
          "regularMarketChange": -1.0900002,
          "regularMarketTime": "2021-07-02 13:00:00",
          "priceHint": 2,
          "regularMarketPrice": 23.77,
          "regularMarketDayHigh": 24.94,
          "regularMarketDayLow": 23.59,
          "regularMarketVolume": 187927,
          "averageDailyVolume10Day": 686057,
          "averageDailyVolume3Month": 389974,
          "regularMarketPreviousClose": 24.86,
          "regularMarketSource": "FREE_REALTIME",
          "regularMarketOpen": 25.24,
          "exchange": "TOR",
          "exchangeName": "Toronto",
          "exchangeDataDelayedBy": 15,
          "marketState": "CLOSED",
          "quoteType": "EQUITY",
          "symbol": "SCR.TO",
          "underlyingSymbol": null,
          "shortName": "SCORE MEDIA AND GAMING INC",
          "longName": "Score Media and Gaming Inc.",
          "currency": "CAD",
          "quoteSourceName": "Delayed Quote",
          "currencySymbol": "$",
          "fromCurrency": null,
          "lastMarket": null,
          "marketCap": 1196655488
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: The code you have posted won't work with the JSON you've posted. There's also code missing - preparing the statement, binding the values. If this is your code nothing will work. Since you say that the first row is inserted, please post the code that does that.

Comment: Thanks, I have put in the rest of the code, hopefully it will help you understand better, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I set up a simplified version of your code, but using your JSON sample, and ran it successfully. Try it with error reporting enabled, or look in the server error log.